# Adding a menu to a custom post type sub page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have added a custom menu to a specific page in my header.php (wordpress 4.0) and it appears correctly on that page: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?page_id=8

Here is the code:

```
<?php if(is_page( 8 )){ /*Add SubMenu Code to Watch Page */?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'watch-menu' ) ); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This page displays a custom post type (Video). Now I would like to add this same menu to any subpages of that custom post type, such as these:

http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?video=trailive-season-1-episode-3

http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?video=tiny-pass-test-2

http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?video=the-long-haul-john-muir-trail

I tried this:

```
<?php if ( is_post_type_archive('video') ) { ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'watch-menu' ) ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

with no success. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a singular post is being displayed, use [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular):

```
if( is_singular( 'video' ) ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in each video post the URL contains the word "video" you can accomplish this by checking on each post if there is a "video" in the URL.

```
  // getting the part after the domain and looking if there is the word video inside id     
 <?php if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'video') !== FALSE) ?> 
 //you can be more specific with the "video" part because if for some reason there is non video post that also have the word "video" the menu will be still displayed  
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'watch-menu' ) ); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

The other way is using JavaScript to accomplish this task, you simply need to search for the video id and if it exist you printing the menu.

The lazy way would be to just add the javascript after the wp_head(); in header.php
or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to diggy I came up with this:

```
<?php if(is_page( 8 ) || is_singular( 'video') || is_tax( array( 'video-type', 'videotags', 'video-sport', 'videocat'))){   /*Add SubMenu Code to all Video Post Related Pages */?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'watch-menu' ) ); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```